# Mute a module log

Tags: python, logging, mute

I have one function in my script that gave me annoying warnings. This function is from a module call `processing` and I would like to mute it.

This my code :

```
# Prepare the environment

import sys
import os # Ce module permet d'utiliser les fonctionnalités du système d'exploitation
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]="/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/proj"
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework

sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins') # Folder where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

# Run the algorithm

pwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def xlsx_to_csv():

    import openpyxl
    import pandas as pd

    pd.options.mode.chained_assignment=None # Disbale CopyWarning

    print('Export '+pwd+'/XLSX/input.xlsx to '+pwd+'/CSV/input.csv...')

    input=pd.DataFrame()
    input['Date'],input['Name'],input['UTM32_E'],input['UTM32_N']=pd.to_datetime(pd.read_excel(pwd+'/XLSX/input.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')['Date'],dayfirst=True,errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),pd.read_excel(pwd+'/XLSX/input.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')['Name'],pd.read_excel(pwd+'/XLSX/input.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')['UTM32_E'],pd.read_excel(pwd+'/XLSX/input.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')['UTM32_N']
    input['Date'][0],input['Date'][1]='Permanent','Permanent'
    input.dropna(subset=['Date'],inplace=True)
    input.to_csv(pwd+'/CSV/input.csv',index=False)

xlsx_to_csv()

def windows(a,b,c):

    format_tuiles=[a,b,c] # Dans l'ordre décroissant pour une bonne superposition des couches

    for px in format_tuiles:
        
        processing.run('native:refactorfields',{ 'FIELDS_MAPPING' : [{'expression': '"Date"','length': 10,'name': 'Date','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"Name"','length': 10,'name': 'Name','precision': 0,'type': 10},{'expression': '"UTM32_E"','length': 0,'name': 'UTM32_E','precision': 0,'type': 6},{'expression': '"UTM32_N"','length': 0,'name': 'UTM32_N','precision': 0,'type': 6}], 'INPUT' : 'delimitedtext://file:///Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_TSX/CSV/input.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=UTM32_E&yField=UTM32_N&crs=EPSG:32632&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no','OUTPUT':pwd+'/SHP/input.shp'})
        processing.run('native:buffer',{'DISSOLVE':False,'DISTANCE':2.5,'END_CAP_STYLE':2,'INPUT':pwd+'/SHP/input.shp','JOIN_STYLE':1,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'OUTPUT':pwd+'/SHP/windows_'+str(px)+'px.shp','SEGMENTS':1})
        print(str(px)+'px windows was created')

def extract_stats(a,b,c,parameter,band=1):

    import pandas as pd # Ce module facilite l'exploitation des fichiers CSV

    format_tuiles=[a,b,c]
    output=[pd.DataFrame()]*3
    radar_image=pwd+'/DATA/'+parameter

    print('Extracting statistics for band '+str(band)+' from '+radar_image+'...')

    for file in os.listdir(radar_image):

        i=0
        date=file[14:16]+'/'+file[12:14]+'/'+file[8:12]
        path_to_radar_output=radar_image+'/'+file

        for px in format_tuiles:

            if parameter=='dB' and band==1:
                parameter='K0'
            elif parameter=='dB' and band==2:
                parameter='K3'
            elif parameter=='dB' and band==3:
                parameter='K4'
            elif parameter=='dB' and band==4:
                parameter='K7'

            processing.run('native:zonalstatisticsfb',{'COLUMN_PREFIX':'_','INPUT':pwd+'/SHP/windows_'+str(px)+'px.shp','INPUT_RASTER':path_to_radar_output,'OUTPUT':pwd+'/SHP/stat_'+str(px)+'px.shp','RASTER_BAND':band,'STATISTICS':[2,4]})
            processing.run('native:savefeatures',{'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'','INPUT':pwd+'/SHP/stat_'+str(px)+'px.shp','LAYER_NAME':'','LAYER_OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT':pwd+'/CSV/ouput_'+str(px)+'px_'+parameter+'.csv'})
            temporary_csv=pd.read_csv(pwd+'/CSV/ouput_'+str(px)+'px_'+parameter+'.csv')
            output[i]=pd.concat([output[i],temporary_csv,])
            i+=1
            
    i=0

    for px in format_tuiles: 

        output[i].to_csv(pwd+'/CSV/ouput_'+str(px)+'px_'+parameter+'.csv',index=False)
        i+=1

def clean_shp():

    print('Cleaning '+pwd+'/SHP/...')

    for file in os.listdir(pwd+'/SHP/'):

        if 'windows' in file:
            continue
        else:
            os.remove(pwd+'/SHP/'+file)

# Exit applications

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

This where `processing` is located

```
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins
```

**Trick :**

```
pugliesipc@Pierres-MacBook-Air ~ % python3
Python 3.10.3 (v3.10.3:a342a49189, Mar 16 2022, 09:34:18) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> devnull=open(os.devnull,'w')
>>> sys.stdout=devnull
>>> os.system('/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3.8 /Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/extract_TSX/extract_TSX.py > /dev/null 2>&1')
>>>
```

This solution is not the more convenient because it also throw away `print()`...

That is why I am looking for a better solution.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you also add directory structure (where exactly is run defined inside processing, and what is its relative path to current file) and how are u using logging inside processing ?

Comment: I do not really know the module 'logging' and I am maybe using it the wrong way... I update my post to add the missing informations.

Comment: can you give an example of an annoying warning?

Comment: Warning 1: /Users/pugliesipc/Desktop/OUTPUT_PPC.nosync/Phase_2/DATA/dB/09K0153_20211118T063659_TDX_db.tif: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.
Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Sum of Photometric type-related color channels and ExtraSamples doesn't match SamplesPerPixel. Defining non-color channels as ExtraSamples.